# SQL Select Query w/ Null Parameters

Tags: c#, sql, select

I had an error on 2 similar SQL Select Querys' and my assumption was I'm using NULL incorrectly. Someone took a look and showed me where I was going wrong.

```
string CountHolidayQuery = "SELECT StartDate, EndDate FROM [Holiday] WHERE PayrollNo = @PayrollNo AND Authorised IS NOT Null";
```

and

```
string CountRequestedQuery = "SELECT StartDate, EndDate FROM [Holiday] WHERE PayrollNo = @PayrollNo AND Authorised IS Null";
```

Comment: Please don't write inline SQL like that unless you are aware of the dangers - see [here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp) and [here](https://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=44). Especially if you're working with payroll data...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Authorised = Null` is invalid and should be `Authorised IS Null` or `Authorised IS NOT Null`

Comment: Have done so, Error changed to 
>An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Additional information: No value given for one or more required parameters.

Comment: That is because in your `Is Not Null` statement, you have typed "Autorised" instead of "Authorised"

Comment: Thanks Alfie, can't believe I missed that *Slaps forehead*

Answer (score 4):

In SQL, Null is not treated quite like a value and is in fact a special case, the syntax for this is `Is Null` and `Is Not Null`, for example

```
string CountHolidayQuery = "SELECT StartDate, EndDate FROM [Holiday] WHERE PayrollNo = @PayrollNo AND Autorised Is Not Null";
```

and also

```
string CountRequestedQuery = "SELECT StartDate, EndDate FROM [Holiday] WHERE PayrollNo = @PayrollNo AND Authorised Is Null";
```

In the first statement, which says that `Authorised` should not be null, it is typed incorrectly and instead reads `Autorised`

Answer (score 2):

It should be "`IS NOT` null", query is missing `IS`

```
SELECT StartDate, EndDate FROM [Holiday] WHERE PayrollNo = @PayrollNo AND Autorised IS NOT Null";
```

And the second query  `Authorised = Null` is not a valid `sql` syntax.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are missing the the keyword **is**

so the statement will be as follows:

```
string CountHolidayQuery = "SELECT StartDate, EndDate FROM [Holiday] WHERE PayrollNo = @PayrollNo AND Autorised is NOT Null";
```